# Properly Closing a FileStream after Async Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, asynchronous, nfs

I'm writing a C# application (limited to .NET framework 4.0 or lower (i.e. no Read/WriteAsync)) that is responsible for reading / writing files between a Windows (7 or later) machine and a NFS-mounted Unix-based server.
The client machines are mobile and are expected to be disconnected from the network periodically.  Because of this, I wish to harden my application to gracefully handle disconnects in the middle of a read or write operation (hopefully by accident).

To keep track of whether a timeout has occurred, I asynchronously read (or write) and use the `AsyncWaitHandle` of the `IAsyncResult` returned by `FileStream.BeginRead`:

```cs
private int PerformRead (FileStream readStream,
                         byte [] buffer,
                         int nBytes)
{
    IAsyncResult readResult = null;

    try
    {
        readResult = readStream.BeginRead
            (buffer, 0, nBytes, null, null);

        // If the read was completed, return # of bytes read.
        if (readResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne (1000))
        {
            return readStream.EndRead (readResult);
        }
        // Otherwise, the timeout has elapsed.
        else
        {
            throw new TimeoutException ();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != readResult)
        {
            readResult.AsyncWaitHandle.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

My issue arises with cleaning up my streams in the case of a time out.  It appears that calling `Dispose()` or `Close()` on the stream hangs indefinitely while the connection is severed.  To attempt to remedy this, I explicitly call Win32's `CloseHandle()` on the file handle on a timeout.  This function appears to also block while the connection is severed.  The following represents my treatment of the read stream.

```cs
private void ReadNewFile (string path,
                          byte [] buffer)
{
    IntPtr readHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    FileStream readStream = null;
    try
    {
        readHandle = CreateFile (path
                                 0xc0000000,
                                 0,
                                 IntPtr.Zero,
                                 3,
                                 0x40000000,
                                 IntPtr.Zero);
        SafeFileHandle safeReadHandle = new SafeFileHandle (readHandle, true);
        if (safeReadHandle.IsInvalid)
        {
            throw new Exception ();
        }
        readStream = new FileStream (safeReadHandle,
                                     FileAccess.Read,
                                     4092,
                                     true);
        while (true)
        {
            // Read part of the file into the buffer.
            int bytesRead = PerformRead (readStream, buffer, buffer.Length);

            // If EOF reached, break.
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        // NOTE: Hangs indefinitely if the network cable is unplugged.
        CloseHandle (readHandle);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != readStream)
        {
            // NOTE: Hangs indefinitely if both of the following are true:
            // - Network cable is unplugged (resulting in TimeoutException)
            // - The body of the caught TimeoutException is commented out.
            readStream.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a recommended method of properly disposing of a FileStream for a file that is no longer available?  Note that any call to `BeginRead` will also hang indefinitely if the connection has severed.